# Turn off sending device data to Microsoft

Tags: windows-10

I'm configuring a Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB computer for work. The PC will be used in a factory without any connection to the internet. In `Settings > Privacy > Feedback & diagnostics` there is the option `Send your device data to Microsoft`. I'd like the turn this off (ie. disable it) but the only options are:

```
Basic
Extended
Full (recommended)
```

Is there a registry hack to disable this feature? Or possibly a service I can permanently stop?

Comment: If it's not connected to the Internet, then why care what it's set to?

Comment: I will have no control over whether the machines are connected to the internet or not. Most of the time they'll be completely disconnected and just running the dedicated automation application. I'd rather the OS neither wasted CPU time nor tried to send data that may or may not cause problems in the customers' network. This is simply irrelevant to this device and the applications it will be used for.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using the Enterprise version of Windows 10, you could set the local group policy for "Allow Telemetry" to "0 - Security [Enterprise Only]".

In gpedit.msc:

1. Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Data Collection and Preview Builds
2. Double-click Allow Telemetry
3. In the Options box, select the level 0, and then click OK

Although, as mentioned in a comment above, there's really no point in doing this if the machine isn't connected to a network or completely firewalled off from the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately after installing .NET 3.5 (from the Windows Update site) and rebooting, the entire PC was bricked. We're sending it back to the factory for resetting, so I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: @AlainD Well at least it can't send data to Microsoft now! ;)